# Syntax for counting cases

Tags: spss

I work with SPSS and have difficulty finding/generating a syntax for counting cases.

I have about 120 cases and five variables. I need to know the count /proportion of cases where just one, more than one, or all of the cases have a value of 1 (dichotomous variable). Then I need to compute a new variable that shows the number / proportion of cases which include all of the aforementioned cases (also dichotomous).

For example case number one: var1=1, var2=1, var3=1, var4=0, var5=0 --> newvariable=1.
Case number two: var1=0, var2=0, var3=0, var4=0, var5=0 --> newvariable=1.
And so on...

Can anybody help me with a syntax?
Help would much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Here we can use the sum of the variables to determine your conditions. So using a scratch variable that is the sum, we can see if it is equal to 1, more than 1 or 5 in your example.

```
compute #sum = SUM(var1 to var5).
compute just_one = (#sum = 1).
compute more_one = (#sum > 1).
compute all_one = (#sum = 5).
```

Similarly, `all_one` could be computed using the `ANY` command to evaluate if any zeroes exist, i.e. `compute all_one = ANY(0,var1 to var5).`. These code snippets assume that `var1 to var5` are contiguous in the data frame, if not they just need to be replaced with `var1,var2,var3,var4,var5` in all given instances.

Comment: Thanks alot Andy! Always nice to learn new, even if simple, things!

Comment: Yes no problem @O.S.! - If you feel this satisfactorily answered your question you should check mine (or Robert's) as answered (and preferably upvote as well). Robert's advice is good as well, as the `COUNT` command can count any particular values (or system missing) is a set of variables, which is more general than using the sum of the variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could read up on the logical function ANY in the Command Syntax Reference manual, if you negated a test for ANY with "0", then that is effectively a test for all "1"s.  Use of the COUNT command would be another approach.